# Unable to allow certain websites through firewall. (subdomain)

Tags: networking, firewall, subdomain

I'm working on building a whitelist of certain sites that one is allowed to visit. But I've been struggling with allowing certain websites. For instance 'netacad.com' is put on a whitelist. This whitelist is allowed all traffic through port 80 and 443 but yet the site fails to load everytime. Even sometimes when allowing all traffic to the domain specified it still fails to load. Why is this?

Also when I want people to be able to reach branch.Tree.com I just keep failing. When adding Tree.com the user can connect to Tree.com but not to branch.tree.com. Adding branch.tree.com on itself does not solve anything either. It is an alias for a way complicated name as well, but adding the real name behind it does not solve anything either. Any tips or ideas?
I'm using different methode to filter packets as well: ACL's on the router, dns whitelisting and putting up a firewall (PFSense) but not at the same time. But I had no success so far with any of them.

(the domain in question is hogent.be (and chamillo.hogent.be) which both are sites of my school.

Comment: Are you allowing related and established connections? Both ways? You need to make sure that after the initial connection is allowed to be made that they can continue to communicate

Comment: Yes I did that :/ well certainly on my Vyos router. Not so sure about the PFSense firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have endless headaches from trying to "firewall" encrypted websites.  Let me explain why:

1. Everything is encrypted.  You cannot effectively see the contents of the HTTP requests.  There are many methods to deceive anything you can see unencrypted.  (You can spoof SNI to proxy to other websites while filtering solutions will think you're visiting something valid)
2. Modern websites are not self-contained.  You will quickly see that nearly every website in the world uses components that come from 3rd parties.  (i.e. jquery, various rendering frameworks, oauth, etc...)
3. Many companies use 3rd party hosting services like amazon, akamai, and rackspace.  Blocking/Whitelisting a website by IP is only a temporary solution... and you might end up blocking/allowing stuff you didn't realize was hosted on those same servers.  Also, many hosting solutions will use loadbalancers that will push you back & forth between sites.
4. Sites frequently make use of subdomains... which are frequently hosted on multiple servers.  You'll end up jumping down a rabbit-hole of domain-names and the many CDNs associated with that domain.  i.e. www.company.com might have cdn[0-9].images.company.com, cdn[0-9].thumbnails.company.com cdn[1-9].api.company.com, cdn[1-9].video.company.com, ... the list goes on... and can be dozens of layers deep.

Depending on how/what you are blocking... can cause a huge variety of successes and failures... and the most reliable methods require several different ways of blocking/permitting sites.  A combination of a filtered DNS server, blocking/permitting connections to specific IPs & ports, as well as heuristic engines to reliably filter traffic based on baselines & discovery, is really the best way to reliably prohibit unwanted access.  Unfortunately, the more advanced the system, the more expensive and/or more time consuming they can be.  At some point, you'll have to just call it "good-enough".